# How can we obtain the list of changes performed on WooCommerce order via backend?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking to adjust the stock for manual changes in ordered quantities done via the backend. I've to handle three situations:

1. When a new item is added to the order
2. When an existing item is removed from the order
3. When the quantity of an existing item is changed

I was hoping to use `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` hook for this purpose. However, it doesn't keep any track of changes in the posted information list.

What would be the appropriate hook/method to obtain the list of item/quantity changes?

Comment: I've figured out a way consisting of: `woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta`, `woocommerce_delete_order_items`, and `woocommerce_before_save_order_items`. Although, would appreciate if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: You should first add your customizations code in your answer…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, figured out a way to achieve the desired result. `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` is not the right hook for this purpose. However, some obscure and largely undocumented hooks are useful here.

Here is the code snippet in case someone is looking for a similar solution:

```
//When a new order item is added
add_action('woocommerce_new_order_item', 'su_oqa_add_item', 10, 3);
function su_oqa_add_item( $item_id, $item, $order_id ) {
    $order     = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $product   = $item->get_product();
    // Update product stock
}

//When an order item is deleted
// use before hook to get access to current item status in the order
add_action('woocommerce_before_delete_order_item', 'su_oqa_remove_item');
function su_oqa_remove_item( $item_id ) {
    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_item_id( $item_id );
    $order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $item     = $order->get_items()[$item_id];
    $product  = $item->get_product();
    // Update product stock
}

//When an order/item quantity is updated
add_action('woocommerce_before_save_order_items', 'su_oqa_save_items', 10, 2);
function su_oqa_save_items( $order_id, $posted ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $qtys  = $posted['order_item_qty'];
    foreach ($qtys as $item_id => $qty) {
        $item    = $items[$item_id];
        $product = $item->get_product();
        // Update product stock
    }
}
```